# python gtk poo programming many files?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

the code of my program becomes heavier and I would like to separate it into many files.

I found a single tutorial whose code here is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

#Box.py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk,  GdkPixbuf

from BoxBoutton import BoxBoutton

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        sublayout = BoxBoutton()

        box.pack_start(sublayout, True, True, 0)
        self.add(box)

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The second:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

#BoxBoutton.py

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class BoxBoutton(Gtk.Grid):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Grid.__init__(self)

        btn = Gtk.Button(label="Mon super bouton")
        self.attach(0, 0, 1, 1)
```

but I have this error:

```
TypeError: Gtk.Grid.attach() takes exactly 6 arguments (5 given)
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You forgot the child in the attach method of Gtk.Grid. I've edited the answer to explain the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Connect `Gtk.main_quit` to the `destroy` event, not `delete-event`. This is more semantically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the child in the [`attach` method of Gtk.Grid](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Grid.html#Gtk.Grid.attach).

> attach(child, left, top, width, height)

try the following:

```
self.attach(btn, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```